# AutoUnlock a Windows User Session

Tags: windows, unlock, credential-providers

Recently, I have been working on a CredentialProvider in order to unlock automatically (the trigger can be any event, so let’s say the end of a timer) a Windows Vista (or more recent version) user session.

For that I read some useful articles on the subject, the change between GINA and this new architecture. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx.

I think, like everyone in the process of creating a custom CredentialProvider, I didn’t start from scratch but from the sample code provided by Microsoft. And then I tried to change the behaviour (things like logging) in the different functions.

So in the end I can use the custom CredentialProvider, enter the SetUsageScenario methods but still I cannot reach the Set or GetSerialization method. From what I’ve understood in the technical documentation on CredentialProvider (still provided by Microsoft) theses two methods should be called automatically. Is there something I missed ?

Also, my original idea was to get an authentication package using Kerberos in order to perform an implicit user authentication. I got this idea by seeking information on other SO or MSDN threads like

Is this approach the good one ?

Thank you very much for your time answering my questions. Any clarifications are welcomed, even if they don’t directly resolve my problems :-)

Answer (score 1):

`SetSerialization` and `GetSerialization` functions are called from your provider by `LogonUI`. 
After user enters username/password and presses ENTER button, LogonUI calls `GetSerialization` function and provides a pointer, as one of  the four parameters, that will point in future to `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION` structure created and filled by you, and then this structure will be sent from `LogonUI` to `Winlogon` to perform authentication. 
I don't know how to make LogonUI to call `GetSerialization` from your credential provider code and as far as I know you can't call `GetSerialization` by your own because where will you pass your filled `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION` structure if no one requested it, but only `LogonUI` can path it to `Winlogon`?

There is a document called "[Credential Provider Technical Reference](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=93340)", there you can read some details about credential providers. In the [Shell samples folder](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ShellRevealed/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2871) there is a strange folder called "Autologon", maybe it will help you! Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you need to set autologon flag to true in your implementation of the `ICredentialProviderCredential::SetSelected(BOOL *pbAutoLogon)` and `ICredentialProvider::GetCredentialCount` methods.

Next, you need to call `ICredentialProviderEvents::CredentialsChanged` when your timer is hit.
LogonUI will recreate your credentials, and because autologon is set to true it will call your `GetSerialization()` method.

Comment: I understand this is a really old post, but how do you call ICredentialProviderEvents::CredentialsChanged in a CredentialProviderV2?