# Windows CredentialProvider autologon via event still shows login-button

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers

I've written a custom CredentialProvider listening to events sent via bluetooth.
So far everything works fine. Except the fact that after sending the event the login screen changes and shows a single button "Sign in" below the username.
As stated in the answers to [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734982/autounlock-a-windows-user-session) I did he following to achieve autologon:

```
HRESULT CMobileCredential2::SetSelected(_Out_ BOOL *pbAutoLogon)
{
    LOG_FUNCTION;
    *pbAutoLogon = true;
    return S_OK;
}
```

and in the eventhandling code I call:

```
HRESULT hr = _pcpe->CredentialsChanged(_upAdviseContext);
if (S_OK != hr)
{
    LOG_ERROR("Could not login!");
}
```

I thought that the LogonUI would automatically log me in when I set autologon to true? Why do I have to click on another button? Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

**EDIT:**

The following is to be found in the "Credential Provider Technical Reference" from Microsoft:

> In Windows 10, if a credential provider wants to autologon the user
>   where we think may be inappropriate, we will paint a “sign in” button
>   as a speed bump.

I think that's the point I'm hitting here, but what is inappropriate? The password used consists of lower and uppercase characters as well as some numbers. Is there any possibility to cirumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a few days I stumbled upon [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/1a0f9fa9-d0f2-4646-adaa-d5214606f895/windows-10-autologon-by-custom-credential-provider-cannot-be-completed?forum=windowssecurity) in the microsoft-forums, that contained the solution.

As it seems, Windows does not trust the custom credential enough to bypass this "speed bump", when `pbAutoLogon` is set to true in `SetSelected(_Out_ BOOL *pbAutoLogon)`.
However it trusts the custom provider, so setting `pbAutoLogonWithDefault` to true in

```
GetCredentialCount(
    _Out_ DWORD *pdwCount,
    _Out_ DWORD *pdwDefault,
    _Out_ BOOL *pbAutoLogonWithDefault)
```

seems to do the trick, as GetCredentialCount is always called before calling

```
GetSerialization(_Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE *pcpgsr,
    _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION *pcpcs,
    _Outptr_result_maybenull_ PWSTR *ppwszOptionalStatusText,
    _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon)
```

of the custom credential.